# Only one tab of my tabbar wont rotate - the rest are good

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, uitabbarcontroller

i have tabbar application that i want to be rotated Portrait & PortraitUpsideDown.
all my other tabs are ok and rotated.
the only difference is that view have designed xib as well.

this is the code i implement to support the orientation.
as i mention before - all my other tabs working and rotating.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad{
        self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

my app support 4.3+ IOS.
Please help me fix it - i must send it to apple ASAP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed it,
the problem was that i allocated my view controller with custom `init` method and i forgot to load the `self = [super init...]`  inside.

Well. hope this helps someone in the future !